# capturing the duration of a touch on ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, touch

I am trying to capture the duration elapsed between touch start and end, and cant seem to get a consistent behavior no matter what I try.

I have tried a few different solutions, but the behavior is always sporadic. Here is an example of what I am currently trying(below).

I have alerts in place for the long and short touch, but there just seems to be no consistency in the result.

I do see a similar question has been asked here before 'get-the-duration-of-a-touch-in-javascript' but that solution produces the same uncertain results.

Any advise would be really appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $IndividualItem = $(".wrapperWithHover li a");
    var touchStartTime;
    var touchStartLocation;
    var touchEndTime;
    var touchEndLocation;
    $IndividualItem.bind('touchstart', startOfTouch);
    $IndividualItem.bind('touchend', endOfTouch);
    $IndividualItem.bind('touchmove', endOfTouch);


 function startOfTouch(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var d = new Date();
     touchStartTime = d.getTime();

}
function endOfTouch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var d = new Date();
     touchEndTime= d.getTime();
     doTouchLogic();
}

function doTouchLogic() {
     var duration = touchEndTime - touchStartTime;
     if (duration <= 1500) {
         alert('1');
               }
     if (duration > 1500) {
          alert('2');
     }       
    duration = null;

}






$('.wrapperWithHover li a').each(function() {

   var timeout,
       longtouch;

   $(this).bind('touchstart', function() {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          longtouch = true;
      }, 1000);
   }).bind('touchend', function() {
       if (longtouch) {
          // It was a long touch.
       }
       longtouch = false;
       clearTimeout(timeout);
   });

});

});
```

here is a small snip of html I'm using for testing.(had to remove the a hrefs as stackoverflow prevented me from submitting the question with them there.)

> - test
> - test
> - test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to capture the `touchmove` event. Because of that `endOfTouch` method is called on `touchmove` event before even `touchend` has happened.

Remove this line from your code and try. It should give you proper result.

```
$IndividualItem.bind('touchmove', endOfTouch);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I actually put that in after I started experiencing this problem. The problem exists without it as well.